# How to Select 3 random rows per group in same table - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has multiple categories (c) & I'd like to select 3 random rows for each category each time I run this query. I got it to select 3 just fine but noticed it wasn't selecting random rows, but instead the same rows each time. So I'm back to square one with my query.

```
select PLAYERID, 
NAME,
RACEID,
VALUE,
MA, 
ST, 
AG,
LEVEL,
SKILLS,
XP,
TYPE
FROM FAPLAYER
GROUP BY TYPE
ORDER BY RAND()
```

I'm trying to get 3 of each TYPE from the FAPLAYER table where I have probably around 50 different TYPE's.

Here's my query output for a basic [query with RAND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8vLg.png)

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1**: Looks like "*GROUP BY TYPE*" is giving you trouble. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM FAPLAYER
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3;
```

**Solution 2**:
Do you have a column with ID which auto increment? If so then you can do the following max=50, min=1:

```
SET @rand_id = (SELECT FLOOR((RAND() * (max-min+1))+min));

SELECT *
FROM FAPLAYER
WHERE RACEID = @rand_id
```

Comment: I did try your original query before posting but it only outputs 3 rows. I was trying to get 3 rows per type. Type is a column in the data. `SELECT ID,
PLAYERID,
NAME,
VALUE,
MA,
ST,
AG,
AV,
LEVEL,
SKILLS,
TYPE
FROM FAPLAYER
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3;`

Comment: I have about 50 different TYPE's that I'm trying to get 3 random rows from each of. So I might have 10 of TYPE A & 15 of TYPE B & so on for 50 or so more different TYPE's. I was trying to get 3 random from each TYPE in a single query or at least one of each TYPE in a single query that I can export & import into a new table.

Comment: How about create a temp table and insert 1 of each type that you want into it and do a select statement off of that?

Comment: We actually got this working using a stored procedure & another table to hold the inserts from the sproc. It's not pretty but it did work.

Comment: Yeah it's long way but i'm glad you got it going @michaeltrieb!